# revert kernel version change

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm trying to intstall `virtualbox-dkms`, and trying the usual `sudo apt-get- install virtualbox-dkms` yields:

```
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.10 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.17.0-focaltech-debug
Building initial module for 3.17.0-focaltech-debug
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.0-focaltech-debug is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.17.0-focaltech-debug (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found

invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

Reading around, this seems to be a problem with my kernel version. How can I change my kernel from `3.17.0-focaltech-debug` to a virtualbox compatible version?

**EDIT: I've changed my kernel version to 3.19.0-31-generic, here are the updated outputs:**

**Outputs of different commands:**

apt-cache policy virtualbox-dkms

```
virtualbox-dkms:
  Installed: 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3.10-dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

uname -a

```
Linux lydia 3.19.0-31-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 10:21:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dpkg -l '*focaltech*'

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching *focaltech*
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy virtualbox-dkms; lsb_release -a; uname -a`

Comment: Install the latest kernel `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`, it's version 3.19.0.31.18 and the header package `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid`, reboot your system with this kernel and try it again and give me a report with `@A.B.` in the comments.

Comment: And add the output of `dpkg -l '*focaltech*'`

Comment: @A.B. i've tried installing that kernell and these are the results: [paste](http://chopapp.com/#mu0e4tz6) Different error, still not working though

Comment: Remove the focaltech packages, reboot and give me the output of `uname -a` once again.

Comment: Add the content of `/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: @A.B. i've updated `uname -a` in the main question. The file you requested is in this [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13104594/)

Comment: It's an option for you to use VirtualBox 5? I have found at least one bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1457776

Comment: @A.B. yes, how could I install that version? Can I do it via apt-get or do I have to download it from virtualbox.org?

Comment: Try this: https://launchpad.net/~costamagnagianfranco/+archive/ubuntu/locutusofborg-ppa/

Comment: @A.B. That solved it! Thank you! Please write an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this PPA was a good idea. Please check also the Oracle PPA. Remove VirtualBox again and the PPA and try this instructions https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads don't forget to change the distribution name for the repository.